# Swift 2 - Array - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: arrays, swift2

How can I prevent my app to crash if an array is empty?

```
var UserVideosInfo = [[String]]()

@IBAction func actionBtn(sender: UIButton) {
userVideoInfo = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserVideos") as! [[String]]
}
```

If the array is empty `userVideosInfo` crashes saying:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have tried:

```
if var userVideoInfoArray:[[String]] = UserVideosInfo {

            userVideoInfoArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserVideosJSON") as! [[String]]
        }
```

Comment: Use as? instead of as! It seems the array is not empty, the array is nil

Comment: I cannot, Xcode marks it as an error : `did you mean to use '!' or'?"?`

Comment: yep if I use `as?` Xcode fails

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to NSUserDefault instead.

With your attempt to retrieve the object with the key "UserVideos", NSUserDefaults might have returned nil. It was then explicitly unwrapped into an array, and that causes the program to crash.

Please verify the existence of userVideoInfo first before proceeding.

```
var UserVideosInfo: [[String]]?

@IBAction func actionBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    userVideoInfoOrNil = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserVideos")

    if userVideoInfo = userVideoInfoOrNil as! [[String]] {
        //Do stuff with userVideoInfo
    } else {
        //Value is nil
    }
}
```

Comment: it fails saying `Value of type [[String]] can never be nil,`

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it by registering the key/value pair as Apple recommends.

In AppDelegate add as soon as possible

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["UserVideos" : [[String]]()]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

The benefit is that `UserVideos` can never be `nil` and then you can safely write

```
userVideoInfoArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserVideos") as! [[String]]
```

Please read the section about registering default values in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html)

Answer (score -1):

If I use the code below the app its not crashing

```
    if self.Videos.count >0{
Videos = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Videos") as! [[String]])
            }
```